# ng-repeat in angularjs when $scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First, I get data from server and set to `$scope.data` and use it to show in table by ng-repeat. Then I continue get data from server then concat with old `$scope.data` (`$scope.data=$scope.data.concat(newdata)`) => Broswer will draw some new rows of new data.

But I don not know the old data (ex `$scope.data[0]`, not change value) will be re-draw or not? Can you let me know.

Comment: did my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

to avoid 're-draw' you have to use 'track by'

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

> To minimize creation of DOM elements, ngRepeat uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. For example, if an item is added to the collection, ngRepeat will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them.

example :

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
 {{n}}
</div>
```

If you work with object you can use a field (with no duplicate value) as tracker

```
<div ng-repeat="model in collection track by model.id">
  {{model.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to push your array

```
$scope.data.push.apply($scope.data,newdata);
```

Please check this code for reference purpose

```
$scope.moreResultsBoats = function() {  
            $scope.pagIndex = $scope.pagIndex + 1;                                 
            Boat.query({pagIndex: $scope.pagIndex}, 
                function success(result) {
                    console.log('Ejecuting callback. Result:' + result);
                    $scope.boats.push.apply($scope.boats, result);      
                }
            );                              
        };
```

Comment: he didn't ask how to get the data or concat them. I think he ask if the ng-repeat rebuild all the html element DOM or just add the new element ( so it rebuild all with `track by` )

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.data[0]` data won't change because you are using `concat` with previous data, that will keep on same position and new data will add afterwards

NOTE: new data type should same then it would work correctly.

For instance:

```
$scope.data = [1,2,3]
newdata = [4,5,5];
$scope.data=$scope.data.concat(newdata);
```

Output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,5]
```

Comment: he didn't ask how to get the data. I think he ask if the ng-repeat rebuild all the html element DOM or just add the new element ( so it rebuild all with `track by` )

Comment: if $scope.data is modify then dome manipulation will modify even he used in `ng-repeat` or other in expression

Comment: NO. see my answer. "To minimize creation of DOM elements, ngRepeat uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. For example, if an item is added to the collection, ngRepeat will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them."